# MacBook not powering on

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, power, repair

I was travelling the other day, and after putting my MacBook Pro through the X-ray machine, I picked it up and got a small shock like a static electric discharge.

I thought nothing of it, but after landing and trying to power on my Mac, I got nothing. When I say nothing I mean nothing. No response whatsoever, no backlight, no battery warning icon, no fan noise, no keyboard backlight, no warmth from the CPU, nothing, literally like an empty shell.

This was super concerning so I plugged it in to see if it was simply out of power, but still nothing even after leaving it plugged in for 12+ hours.

I was really worried and was trying to work out what was wrong. I actually left my Mac on my desk unplugged for about 3 days, then I plugged it in and waited a little while, then tried to feel for warmth either from the power adaptor or from the MacBook itself. I can usually feel a bit of warmth while it's charging, but this time nothing - no heat.

I contacted Apple and told them the issue, but since it's a 2016 MacBook Pro 15", it's out of warranty and they said a mail-in repair would cost around £700 including tax. I thought this was crazy as they don't even know what the problem is and there's obviously no physical damage to the Mac - it was in my rucksack the whole time minus taking it out for the X-ray machine.

I'm truly stumped as to what is causing the problem, did the static electric shock have something to do with it either frying the logic board or breaking the battery, or was that a coincidence and something else is causing the problem.

I refuse to pay the £700 unless it's definitely something like the logic board that's causing the problem. Also most computer repair shops are closed near me until after the new year. I actually have exams in early January so I'm really worried about not having my computer working.

As a little bit more information: I actually had the keyboard replaced through Apple's butterfly keyboard programmers early September, where I think they also replaced the batteries as part of the shell. Obviously I don't know if this has anything to do with the issue but thought it was worth noting - I'm also just 13 days out of the 90 day warranty provided after that service unfortunately.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue? Or any idea on how I should proceed? Should I try and go to a computer repair shop to see if I can at least get the issue diagnosed though this is hard to do due to the time of year and the pandemic or course.

As a note: I have tried resetting the SMC, NVRAM etc. But this does nothing - the Mac looks completely dead as I said above.

Comment: Static could have killed any component. You're probably going to need a repair shop to diagnose.

Comment: @Tetsujin I thought MacBooks would have some sort of static protection. Strange that it seems nothing turns on at all, and the battery does not seem to charge though. Is it even related to the static? Could be a battery problem? I don't know

Comment: No computer is fully immune to random electric charges. Not to mention that being the *only* symptom that stands out and we are guessing from experience. It is truly impossible to troubleshoot hardware via the internet, we can only guess. And the fee that Apple mentioned for mail in repair is likely the maximum cost and as Apple does not do board level repairs it is probably the cost of replacing the Mac.

Comment: As @SteveChambers says, if it is a logic board issue, they just replace the entire MLB unit, because many components are soldered to it (i.e. CPU, GPU, Memory, etc), so they can't just replace an isolated component on the MLB, but rather have to replace the whole unit. I agree the price they quoted sounds around the upper limit, as my MBP late 2013's logic board (max specifications) was replaced last year for around AU$800 (£450), out of warranty. Finally, UK consumer laws may provide statutory warranty on the keyboard/topcase replacement, which may be beyond Apple's 90 days warranty